# Send data from chained select to a different page

Tags: javascript

Hey all i have this chained select. source: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/

I got it to work but i have some problems posting the selected result. Can anyone help me. I get the main and sub category from the database. when i try to send it to post.php i get undefined index. how can i post a variable from java to php. any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#category").change(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#type").html(data);
            });
        });
        $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
            var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');


            if(cat>0 && type>0)
            {
            var result = $("select#type option:selected").html();

            $.ajax({
            data: result,
            url: 'post.php',
            method: 'POST', // or GET
            success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
    }
});




            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body><p>
        <?php include "select.class.php"; 

        ?>
        <form id="select_form" action="post">
            Choose a category:<br />
            <select id="category">
                <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
            </select>
        <br /><br />
        Choose a type:<br />
        <select  id="type">
             <option  value="0">choose...</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
        </form>
        <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Post.php

```
<?php

echo $_POST['result'];

?>
```

Comment: Try doing `data : {result : result},` instead, and you can use the proper keys etc

Comment: i still get the same error with {result : result},

Comment: if i use document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result; and can output it with <div id="result"> but for some reason i cannot send it as is to my php document. How can i achieve this. Any1? :(